# How do I tell if the current revision is the published one

Tags: entities, database, nodes

I'm loading each entity and trying to see whether or not the entity is the latest revision.

```
  $query = db_select($entity_items['revision table'], 'revision')
    ->fields('revision', array($entity_items['id'], $entity_items['revid']))
    ->condition('revision.' . $entity_items['id'], $data->$entity_items['id']);
  $revisions = $query
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc($entity_items['revid']);

  $entities = array();
  foreach ($revisions as $key => $revision) {
    $loaded_revision = entity_revision_load($entity_key, $key);
}
```

The $loaded_revision object has multiple keys that could be related to whether this revision is the current published revision.

This is at the bottom of the object:

```
[path] => Array ( [pid] => 1256 [source] => node/18205 [alias] => content/path [language] => en-US ) [workbench_moderation] => Array ( [current] => stdClass Object ( [hid] => 47961 [vid] => 39926 [nid] => 18205 [from_state] => published [state] => draft [uid] => 0 [stamp] => 1387146582 [published] => 0 [current] => 1 [title] => Title [timestamp] => 1387146582 ) [published] => stdClass Object ( [hid] => 45461 [vid] => 37599 [nid] => 18205 [from_state] => published [state] => published [uid] => 4 [stamp] => 1375802201 [published] => 1 [current] => 0 [title] => Title [timestamp] => 1387146582 ) [my_revision] => stdClass Object ( [hid] => 42605 [vid] => 35755 [nid] => 18205 [from_state] => published [state] => published [uid] => 4 [stamp] => 1371655937 [published] => 0 [current] => 0 [title] => Title [timestamp] => 1371655937 ) ) )
```

From what I'm reading, vid 37599 is the current version? Is that correct? Would it be based on the published and current key?

It seems that if current is 1, and published is 1, then that would mean that the revision is the current published revision.